# XPath to find attributes with illegal characters

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am trying to use XPath to find a node with an attribute of a specific value.
The code below is working for normal strings, but fails when there is an escaped character, like & or '.

```
string query = "question & answer";
query = query.replace("&", "&amp;");

string nodePath = string.Format("/QUESTIONS/QUESTION[@text='{0}']", query);

XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(nodePath);
```

Is there anyway to find attributes with a value containing an escaped character?

Comment: Executing `/QUESTIONS/QUESTION[@text='question &amp; answer']` should work fine for finding a `Question` element with the text attribute equaling `question &amp; answer`. The source XML also must have this encoded, otherwise it wouldn't be well-formed XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't do replacement of special character:

```
string query = "question & answer";
string nodePath = string.Format("/QUESTIONS/QUESTION[@text='{0}']", query);
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(nodePath);
```

This will match

```
<QUESTION text="question &amp; answer"/>
```

If you need to search something with single quote character, then use double quotes for attribute text:

```
string query = "question's answer";
string nodePath = string.Format("/QUESTIONS/QUESTION[@text=\"{0}\"]", query);
```

Matches

```
<QUESTION text='question&apos;s answer'/>
```

Just use double quotes for text attribute value if you have single quote inside text.

Comment: Thanks, that works for &amp; but if I try the same for &apos; I get an error: /QUESTIONS/QUESTION[@text='question's answer']' has an invalid token

Comment: @glboothby hold on, I'll check